# VScode makes my ubuntu screen flash randomly

Tags: linux, ubuntu, visual-studio-code, electron, ubuntu-20.04

I have been using Ubuntu for years and I never had any problems, a few weeks ago he started to have a problem, I don't know what it is, the screen keeps flashing, there comes a time that stops but after some time he returns.

I recorded a video about the problem:
https://www.loom.com/share/f941ca79f2fd4f7f8aad13324c14a4f4

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since it seems that you don't have a specific programming question but rather a question about a bug or software problem you're experiencing, you could try to [file a bug report](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose) with Visual Studio Code itself. You will most likely get more help there.

Comment: fwiw, I've seen this on OSX. It's infrequent but odd.